# Why are my pseudo-classes overriding display:none?

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I have a div that appears as an "X" (used to close a window):

```
<div class="alertwrapper" style="display:inline-block;">
<div class="obj"></div> 
<div class="x"></div>   //<-----ELEMENT IN QUESTION
</div>
```

The following are the CSS properties of this element:

```
.x {
    display: none !important;
   position: absolute !important;
left:0;
top:0;
    transition: transform .25s ease-in-out;
    z-index:999;
}

.x:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    //Here, I've also tried display:none !important;
    left: 48%;
    margin-left:-495px;
    right: 0;
    top: 115px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: center;
    z-index:999;
}
.x:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    //Here, I've also tried display:none !important;
    left: 48%;
    margin-left:-495px;
    right: 0;
    top: 115px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: center;
    z-index:999;
}
```

This div should not be displayed until another element is clicked, at which point, it should appear, as defined by the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('body').on('click', '.ActiveQuestionCycler', function() {
             $("div.x").fadeIn(300).delay(1500);
             $("div.obj").fadeIn(300).delay(1500);
    });
});
</script>
```

When the page loads, however, the div "x" is visible, before `.ActiveQuestionCycler` is clicked. (The display is not set to none.) I think this has to do with the pseudo-classes `before` and `after` overriding this but I can't figure out why.

(`div.obj` DOES fade in when `.ActiveQuestionCycler` is clicked.)

There are no error alerts in the source.

Comment: Snoops, is there a working example of your code anywhere, like a codeply project, codepen, or jsfiddle?

Comment: I'll do a simpler JSFiddle momentarily

Comment: why do you have so many style tags? i would consolidate them all into one stylesheet

Comment: @cup_of While i'm building the site, it helps me keep track of the separate functions. (I learned the little that I do know about coding through trial and error, so I have no formal training in formatting 'etiquette' ha.)

Comment: for sure, just heads up its best practice to have a separate linked stylesheet with all your styles, you can separate it with a bunch of spaces if you want

Comment: @cup_of Will do - Thank you for the pointer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comment `/// STYLE SETTINGS FOR THE QUESTION CONTAINER AND CLOSE "X" BUTTON` on line 109 is invalid. Change it to:

`/* STYLE SETTINGS FOR THE QUESTION CONTAINER AND CLOSE "X" BUTTON */`

and it should work. Remember to drop that `display: none;` into the `.x`

So it will look like:

```
.x {
    display: none;
    /* your other styles */
}
```

While `// comment` is normal for most programming languages, regular css does not accept it and css comments go like this `/* comment */`

Comment: Excellent catch! Never even looked at that - works perfectly now. (I'm surprised it worked at all before.)